# Is it possible to upload pinescript from local filesystem?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to write my pinescript on my local filesystem and then upload it into TV?

I've been looking in the docs and on SO but the only solution seems to be to copy and paste the script into the web-based editor.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to upload them programmatically but I can't even find an "Import" or "Upload from File" or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no import function. You must use etiher the web-based editor or desktop application.